# program not taking an input after terminating a loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program which calculates the sum of n integers. But when I try to run the program, it doesn't take input for `val2`.

```
int main()
{
    int val1 = 0;
    cout << "Enter the integers (enter '|' to terminate input): ";
    vector<int> elements = {};

    while (cin >> val1) {
        elements.push_back(val1);
    }

    cout << "Enter the number to find the sum of integers: ";
    int val2;
    cin >> val2;

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < val2; ++i) {
        sum = sum + elements[i];
        cout << "The sum of first " << val2 << " elements is " << sum << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the header

```
#include <limits>
```

and before this code snippet

```
cout << "Enter the number to find the sum of integers: ";
```

write

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

The problem is that after entering the symbol `'|'` the input stream is in the erroneous state and you need to skip non-digit symbols in the input buffer.

Comment: @zerocool When you are entering  '|' then an error is occurred because this character is not a valid character of an integer number. This character will be still in the input buffer. You have to ignore (skip) it.

Comment: @zerocool There was a typo. Place a dot instead of the comma after std::cin.:) For example std::cin.clear();